# Why are characters missing from rendered text when using XeLaTex with utf8 and an installed font?

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode

Why are some characters missing from rendered text? I am using XeLaTeX, the UCAS block (Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics) of Unicode fonts and an installed font on my system.

1. Some of the typed characters are not rendered.
2. There seem to be hidden sequences in the actual code; I say that because when moving the cursor through the code with the arrow keys, there are specific places where several strikes are necessary.  These are consistently in the same place and the same number of strikes to move the cursor.  I was receiving the compilation error "��Text line contains an invalid character," until I backspaced over them.  The code itself still looks **exactly** the same.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Pitabek}            

\begin{document}

My name is Jayse Cardinal-Tahkiné.\\
ᒉᐦᔅ ᑳᕐᑏᓈᓪ ᓐᑎᔑᓂᐦᑳᔅ᙮ \\
ᐁ  is CANADIAN SYLLABICS  E

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the rendered code is missing several characters in the second line: ᒉᐦ ᑳᑏᓈ ᑎᔑᐦᑳ

[image: rendered font]

Comment: I don't have your font; with two other fonts I get [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuAzU.png)

Comment: Thank you.  So evidently this is a font-specific issue; I tried with another font (OskiEast) and the code rendered correctly.  That begs the question:  why would **any** unicode font would fail when the characters are part of the font? Will all fonts have to be put through some kind of rendering test prior to use?

Comment: one possibility is that the font is incomplete/bad. The other that you have two versions of the font - that can confuse xetex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the `pitabek.ttf` font and tried the example also with other fonts having the glyphs for Canadian Aboriginal Syllabic.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Euphemia UCAS}
\newfontfamily{\djs}{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily{\pita}{pitabek.ttf}[Path=./]
\begin{document}

My name is Jayse Cardinal-Tahkiné.\\
ᒉᐦᔅ ᑳᕐᑏᓈᓪ ᓐᑎᔑᓂᐦᑳᔅ᙮ \\
ᐁ  is CANADIAN SYLLABICS  E

\djs

My name is Jayse Cardinal-Tahkiné.\\
ᒉᐦᔅ ᑳᕐᑏᓈᓪ ᓐᑎᔑᓂᐦᑳᔅ᙮ \\
ᐁ  is CANADIAN SYLLABICS  E

\pita

My name is Jayse Cardinal-Tahkiné.\\
ᒉᐦᔅ ᑳᕐᑏᓈᓪ ᓐᑎᔑᓂᐦᑳᔅ᙮ \\
ᐁ  is CANADIAN SYLLABICS  E

\end{document}
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

The log file contains

```
Missing character: There is no ᔅ in font [./pitabek.ttf]/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ᕐ in font [./pitabek.ttf]/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ᓪ in font [./pitabek.ttf]/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ᓐ in font [./pitabek.ttf]/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ᔅ in font [./pitabek.ttf]/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;!
```

and this explains the issue: the font doesn't have the required glyphs.